# Excel Network days formula using multiple Holiday conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am working on a vacation dashboard where I want I am trying to calculate the number of working days between two days using networkdays but I have different holidays list for different set of people.

I have two Holiday list one according to Indian calendar and one according to US calendar. My excel sheet looks something like this.

** Excel Screen shot**
[image]

I have put a table reference for each of these small tables.In column A I have name of the employees which might be an Indian Employee or an US employee. The employee will enter the details of there vacation type, start and end date till column D and the **Column E** will then calculate the Number of days leaves taken using the start and the end date.

=NETWORKDAYS(vaca[[#This Row],[Start Date]],vaca[[#This Row],[End Date]],Holidays[Holidays])

I have a list of Holidays separately for both the US and Indian Calender (column K& L)and the different employee list both Indian and US in column I.

I now want to calculate the number of days in column E such that when it sees the name of the employee in column **A** it calculates in on the basis of the US and UK holiday calender and the employee name.

For example 
if the Name of the employee in column A fall is in the employee_india table the the network days should take Holiday India calendar and if the name of the employee in column A is in employee US then use US holiday calendar. i have used multiple IF statements and a true and false condition but nothing works.
please suggest the solution for the same

Comment: There is no relationship between the employee name and their location and location and the corresponding holiday calendar. Keep Just one Employee table and add a column in it to identify the location. Same way Keep one calendar table and add one more column to identify the location. Normalize your data this way and try one again. If you are still not able to figure out the formula then comeback.

Comment: I did the changes but then I am not able to understand how do I refer the excel to choose the holiday calendar basis the country. Sorry but the formula still doesnt work

Comment: This may help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495524/simplify-networkdays-function-contains-several-if-options/42496040#42496040)